# Can Chrome open shortcuts in the same instance/tab?

Tags: google-chrome, shortcuts, javascript, hotkeys, bookmarks

I have a bookmark that executes javascript code, and I want to make a shortcut to it so that I can assign a hotkey to it, but when I do that, chrome launches a new tab with the bookmark/javascript code, making it useless because I need the javascript code to be executed on the already open page. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, shortcut is always opening a new instance of Chrome since you call chrome.exe process in it that starts new exception thread.

If you open Task manager you could find that every tab is shown as a separate Chrome.exe process.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Dang. I was hoping there would be a switch or any way to make it just execute a command in the already existing tab, but I guess not.